# COPY file contents into Postgres table that is in PVC

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

Struggling to wrap my brain around this one...

So I need to execute a Postgres `COPY` command in a PHP program like the following:

```
COPY _data_20200404_193855 FROM '/mnt/files/imports/CopyFlatFile.csv.tab' DELIMITER E'\t' CSV HEADER
```

The `/mnt/files/xls-imports/CopyFlatFile.csv.tab` is the PVC location, but Postgres Pod is thinking it is a location in the Pod, so it says it can't find the file.

I can manually move the file out of the PVC and into the Postgres Pod with a combination of `scp` and `kubectl cp` and the command executes perfectly after copying it into pgAdmin and running it.

Not an ideal method and not very efficient as I'd like the program to handle it.

Any suggestions for how to handle this?

Worst case scenario, I rewrite it to construct a massive `INSERT INTO` statement, but not sure if it can handle that much data being held in memory. If not, I'll just break it into smaller chunks. Oof...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I didn't even have my file storage PVC hooked up to the Postgres Deployment... did that and it is now working. Oversight on my part.

Was...

```
...
          volumeMounts:
            - name: postgres-storage
              mountPath: /var/postgresql
      volumes:
        - name: postgres-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-storage
...
```

So I changed it to:

```
...
            - mountPath: /var/postgresql
              name: postgres-storage
            - mountPath: /mnt/files/xls-imports
              name: file-storage
              subPath: xls-imports
      volumes:
        - name: postgres-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-storage
        - name: file-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: file-storage
...
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is to mount same external filesystem ( such as NFS, CephFS or corresponding SaaS versions like AWS EFS ) to all php and PostgreSQL pods in `ReadWriteMany` [access mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#volume-mode) and use it as a shared temporary directory between all pods.